# What is the error term in Mertens' first theorem for arithmetic progressions?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, asymptotics, approximation

I am asking this question here, since my comment on [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59996/sum-of-log-p-p-for-p-equivalent-to-l-mod-d) on Math Overflow got no responses.

I need an explicit (computable) bound on the $O(1)$ term in the following asymptotic formula:
$$\sum_{\substack{p\le x \\p\equiv a\;(\text{mod} \; q)}}\frac{\log(p)}{p}=\frac{\log(x)}{\phi(q)}+O(1),$$
where $\gcd(a,q)=1$. Specifically for the cases $q=4$ and $a\in\{1,2\}$. However, using the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions, I have not been able to get the error better than $O(\log(\log(n)))$. This is what I have done so far:

let $\pi(x;q,a)$ denote the number of primes less than or equal to $x$ that are congruent to $a$ modulo $q$. By Abel's summation formula, we have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{p\le x \\ p\equiv a (\text{mod}\; q)}}\frac{\log(p)}{p}=\frac{\log(x)}{x}\pi(x;q,a)+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log(t)-1}{t^2}\pi(t;q,a)dt    
\hspace{8mm}(1)\end{equation}
Let $\theta(x;q,a):=\sum_{\substack{p\le x \\ p\equiv a (\text{mod}\; q)}}\log(p)$. Then
\begin{align*}
    \pi(x;q,a)=\frac{\theta(x;q,a)}{\log(x)}+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\theta(t;q,a)}{t\log^2(t)}dt
\end{align*}
by the result on page 142 [here.](https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Eevertsejh/ant16-7.pdf) Therefore:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\log(x)}{x}\pi(x;q,a)=\frac{\theta(x;q,a)}{x}+\frac{\log(x)}{x}\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\theta(t;q,a)}{t\log^2(t)}dt.
\end{align*}
The term $\tfrac{\theta(x;q,a)}{x}=\frac{1}{\phi(q)}+o(1)$, while
$$\frac{\log(x)}{x}\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\theta(t;q,a)}{t\log^2(t)}dt=\frac{\log(x)}{x}O(\frac{x}{\log^2(x)})=O(\frac{1}{\log(x)})=o(1).$$
Thus, it remains to consider the integral in $(1)$. We have
\begin{align*}
 \int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log(t)-1}{t^2}&\pi(t;q,a)dt=\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log(t)}{t^2}\pi(t;q,a)dt-\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\pi(t;q,a)}{t^2}dt. \hspace{6mm} (2)
\end{align*}
Let $\varepsilon$ be defined by $\tfrac{\log(t)\pi(t;q,a)}{t}=\frac{1}{\phi(q)}+\varepsilon(t)$. Then the first integral in the right hand side of $(2)$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
    \int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log(t)\pi(t;q,a)}{t^2}dt=&\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\cdot \frac{\log(t)\pi(t;q,a)}{t}dt=\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\cdot (\frac{1}{\phi(q)}+\varepsilon(t))dt\\[1mm]
    =&\frac{\log(x/2)}{\phi(q)}+\int_{2}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t}dt.
\end{align*}
The second integral in the right hand side of $(2)$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
  \int_{2}^{x}\frac{\pi(t;q,a)}{t^2}dt=&\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t\log(t)}\cdot \frac{\log(t)\pi(t;q,a)}{t}dt\\
  =& \int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t\log(t)}\cdot (\frac{1}{\phi(q)}+\varepsilon(t))dt\\
  =&\frac{\log(\log(x))-\log(\log(2))}{\phi(q)}+\int_{2}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t\log(t)}dt.
\end{align*}
Thus, we have:
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{\substack{p\le x \\ p\equiv q (\text{mod}\; q)}}\frac{\log(p)}{p}=\frac{1}{\phi(q)}+\frac{\log(x/2)}{\phi(q)}-\frac{\log(\tfrac{\log(x)}{\log(2)})}{\phi(q)}+\int_{2}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t}dt-\int_{2}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t\log(t)}dt+o(1)
\end{align*}
Thanks to the result on page 6 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.00085.pdf), if $1\le q\le 1200$ is an integer, and $a$ is coprime to $q$, then
$$\frac{x}{\phi(q)\log(x)}<\pi(x;q,a)<\frac{x}{\phi(q)\log(x)}(1+\frac{5}{3\log(x)})$$
for all $x\ge 50q^2$. Consequently,
$$0<\varepsilon(x)<\frac{5}{2\phi(q)\log(x)}$$
for $x \ge 50q^2$. For our purposes we have $q=4$, so the bound holds for $x\ge 800$. Assuming $x\ge 800$, we then have
\begin{align*}
  \int_{2}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t}dt=\int_{2}^{800}\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t}dt+\int_{800}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t}dt,
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
  0<\int_{800}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t}dt<\frac{5}{2\phi(q)}\int_{800}^x\frac{1}{t\log(t)}dt=\tfrac{5}{2\phi(q)}\log(\log(x))-\tfrac{5}{2\phi(q)}\log(\log(800)).
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
   \int_{2}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t\log(t)}dt=&\int_{2}^{800}\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t\log(t)}dt+\int_{800}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t\log(t)}dt,
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
    0<\int_{800}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)dt}{t\log(t)}<\frac{5}{2\phi(q)}\int_{800}^x\frac{dt}{t\log^2(t)}=\frac{5}{1600\phi(q)\log(800)}-\frac{5}{2\phi(q)\log(x)}.
\end{align*}
As a conclusion, I get that
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{\substack{p\le x \\ p\equiv a (\text{mod}\; q)}}\frac{\log(p)}{p}=const.-\frac{\log(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)})}{\phi(q)}+\frac{\log(x)}{\phi(q)}+\int_{800}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t}dt-\int_{800}^x\frac{\varepsilon(t)}{t\log(t)}dt+o(1).
\end{align*}
However, for the error term(the stuff between $conts.$ and $o(1)$, call it $r(x)$), the best I get is
\begin{align*}\frac{5}{2\phi(q)\log(x)}-\frac{5}{1600\phi(q)\log(800)}-\frac{\log(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)})}{\phi(q)}<r(x)<\frac{2\log(\log(x))}{3\phi(q)}+\frac{\log(\log(2))}{\phi(1)},\end{align*}
which I cannot see is better than $O(\log(\log(x)))$.

It have tried using the Siegel–Walfisz theorem, but so far been unsuccessful. I know the constant in the theorem is not effectively computable, so I don't see how I can get the bound explicit using the theorem.

Comment: Note that the left side is constant for at least $k$ consecutive values of $x$, while the right side isn't, so some error on the order of $(\log(x+k)-\log x)/\phi(k)$ is unavoidable.

Comment: If $k = \mathcal{O}(\log ^\alpha  x)$, then the Siegel–Walfisz theorem implies
$$
\sum_{\substack{p\le x \\p\equiv \ell\;(\text{mod} \; k)}}\frac{\log(p)}{p} = \frac{{\log x}}{{\phi (k)}} + \frac{1}{{\phi (k)}} + \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{t^2 }}\left[ {\theta (t;k,\ell ) - \frac{t}{{\phi (k)}}} \right]dt}  + o(1),
$$ as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: Improving the $O(1)$ term to $C+o(1)$ is the PNT for the arithmetic progression $\ell\bmod k$.

Comment: Note that we subtract the leading term of the asymptotics of $\theta$ inside the integral and so it is no longer $\mathcal{O}(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k=\mathcal{O}(\log^\alpha x)$, then by the Siegel–Walfisz theorem
$$
\theta (x;k,\ell ) = \frac{x}{{\phi (k)}} + \mathcal{O}(xe^{ - c(\alpha )\sqrt {\log x} } ).
$$
Thus, by partial summation,
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{\substack{p\le x \\p\equiv \ell \,(\text{mod} \, k)}}\frac{\log p }{p} & = 
\frac{{\theta (x;k,\ell )}}{x} + \int_1^x {\frac{{\theta (t;k,\ell )}}{{t^2 }}dt} \\ & = \frac{{\theta (x;k,\ell )}}{x} + \frac{1}{{\phi (k)}}\int_1^x {\frac{{dt}}{t}}  + \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{t^2 }}\left[ {\theta (t;k,\ell ) - \frac{t}{{\phi (k)}}} \right]dt} \\ &\quad\; - \int_x^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{t^2 }}\left[ {\theta (t;k,\ell ) - \frac{t}{{\phi (k)}}} \right]dt} \\ 
& = \frac{{\log x}}{{\phi (k)}} + \frac{1}{{\phi (k)}} + \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{t^2 }}\left[ {\theta (t;k,\ell ) - \frac{t}{{\phi (k)}}} \right]dt} \\ & \quad\; - \mathcal{O}(1)\int_x^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{t}e^{ - c(\alpha )\sqrt {\log t} } dt}  + \mathcal{O}(e^{ - c(\alpha )\sqrt {\log x} } ) \\ &
 = \frac{{\log x}}{{\phi (k)}} + \frac{1}{{\phi (k)}} + \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{t^2 }}\left[ {\theta (t;k,\ell ) - \frac{t}{{\phi (k)}}} \right]dt}  + o(1).
\end{align*}
The error term may be improved from $o(1)$ to
$$
\mathcal{O}(\sqrt {\log x} \,e^{ - c(\alpha )\sqrt {\log x} } )=\mathcal{O}(e^{ - d(\alpha )\sqrt {\log x} } ).
$$

Comment: Thanks a Lot for the answer. I have gone through it in great detail, and see what I could have done differently. For one, I could have applied the Abel summation with $1/t$ instead of $\log(t)/t$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\[ \text { something you know }=\sum _{n\leq x}\log n=\sum _{d\leq x}\Lambda (d)\sum _{n\leq x\atop {d|n}}1=\text { main term }-\sum _{d\leq x}\Lambda (d)\left \{ \frac {x}{d}\right \} \approx ...-\sum _{p\leq x}\log p\left \{ \frac {x}{p}\right \} \]

and an asymptotic for this last sum is classical, although I don't know a reference.  I assume it amounts to the PNT.

Perhaps you could look for a reference and see what changes you need to do when looking at arithmetic progressions.  I believe it would be as reuns says above that it's the PNT for AP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer by Gary, we have
$$\sum_{\substack{p\le x \\ p\equiv \ell (\text{mod}\; k)}}=\frac{\log(x)}{\phi(k)}+\beta(k,\ell)+O \left(e^{-d\sqrt{\log(x)}} \right ),$$
for some positive constant $d$,
where
$$\beta(k,\ell)=\frac{1}{\phi(k)}+\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{{t^2 }}\left[ {\theta (t;k,\ell ) - \frac{t}{{\phi (k)}}} \right]dt.$$
If $q_1,q_2,\ldots$ denote the primes $\equiv l\; (\text{mod}\; k)$ in order and $q_0:=1$, then $\theta(t;k,\ell)$ is constant and equal to $\theta(q_n;k,\ell)$ on the interval $[q_n, q_{n+1})$, and so
\begin{align*}
  \beta(k,\ell)\;=&\;\frac{1}{\phi(k)}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{q_n}^{q_{n+1}}\frac{\theta(q_n;k,\ell)}{t^2}-\frac{1}{\phi(k)t}dt\\[1.5mm]
  =\;&\frac{1}{\phi(k)}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( \theta(q_n;k,\ell)\frac{q_{n+1}-q_n}{q_nq_{n+1}}-\frac{\log(q_{n+1})}{\phi(k)}+\frac{\log(q_n)}{\phi(k)}\right ).
\end{align*}
Including only $N$ terms of the sum, we get
\begin{align*}
    \beta_N(k,\ell)=&\frac{1}{\phi(k)}+\sum_{n=0}^{N}\left( \theta(q_n;k,\ell)\frac{q_{n+1}-q_n}{q_nq_{n+1}}-\frac{\log(q_{n+1})}{\phi(k)}+\frac{\log(q_n)}{\phi(k)}\right )\\
    =&\;\frac{1}{\phi(k)}-\frac{\log(q_{N+1})}{\phi(k)}+\sum_{n=0}^{N} \theta(q_n;k,\ell)\frac{q_{n+1}-q_n}{q_nq_{n+1}},
\end{align*}
since all the logarithms except $\log(q_{N+1})$ vanish.
Running the following function in python:

```
import sympy
import math
def series(k,l,N):
    phi = sympy.ntheory.totient(k)
    temp = 1 / phi
    theta = 0
    previous = 1
    for p in sympy.primerange(1, N+1):
        if p % k == l:
            temp += theta * (p-previous)/(p*previous)
            theta += math.log(p)
            previous = p
    temp -= math.log(previous)/phi
    return temp
```

gives $\beta_{10^{10}}(k=4,l=1)=-1.112398254781386\;$ and $\beta_{10^{10}}(k=4,l=3)=-0.5667372304981679$.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2132v1